# Xamarin, How can i contain the first batch of list of rows and columns with a border, like group them together?

Tags: xamarin

I've been trying to put border on these text and the only way i can is taking off grid on every row so now it has borders but then the grid frame is off.  I can't differentiate which part is from row1 or the beginning of list.

```
<StackLayout>

<Label Text="rain Log" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,50,0,0" />

<ListView x:Name="postListView" >

<ListView.ItemTemplate>



<!-- from the post.cs -->
<DataTemplate>
<ViewCell >
<Grid BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

<Grid.RowDefinitions > <!-- 8 rows -->
<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                      
<ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
<ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>                 
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  


<!-- Row 1 -->

<Label Grid.Row="1" FontSize="Medium" Grid.Column="0" Text="right tst:" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" BackgroundColor="cornflowerblue" />   

<Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding drain1vol}" BackgroundColor="cornflowerblue"/> 

<!-- endrow1   -->  

<!-- rain1 Row 1 -->
<Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="nothing" BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>               
<Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding drain2vol}" 
HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="Yellow" /> 

<!-- endrow1   -->      

      </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>

</ListView.ItemTemplate>


</ListView>
</StackLayout> 
</ContentPage>
```

[image]

what i want
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to separate out your item as like group than you can use **SeparatorColor** and its visibility.
Instead of 2 boxview you can also use one grid as wrapper and using **ColumnSpacing** and **RowSpacing**.

```
 <ListView x:Name="postListView" SeparatorVisibility="Default" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SeparatorColor="White">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="1,2,1,0">
                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ColumnSpacing="1" RowSpacing="1">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Grid.Row="0" FontSize="Medium" Grid.Column="0" Text="right tst:" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" BackgroundColor="cornflowerblue" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding drain1vol}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="cornflowerblue"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="nothing"  BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding drain2vol}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="Yellow" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `BoxView` to achieve this function, try the following code :

```
   <StackLayout>
    <Label Text="rain Log" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,50,0,0" />
    <ListView x:Name="postListView"  HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell  >
                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ColumnSpacing="2" RowSpacing="0" BackgroundColor="Black">

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Grid.Row="0" FontSize="Medium" Grid.Column="0" Text="right tst:" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" BackgroundColor="cornflowerblue" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding drain1vol}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="cornflowerblue"/>

                        <!-- thin separator -->
                        <BoxView Color="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HeightRequest="2" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="nothing"  BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding drain2vol}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="Yellow" />

                        <!-- thick separator -->
                        <BoxView Color="Black" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HeightRequest="5" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

The effect is as follows:
[image]

Comment: this will only work if i have a fixed number of rows right? but if the rows are unpredictable like I may have 8 rows, I have to know which row will the boxview be?

Comment: We just define the layout of  ListView ItemTemplate, so It doesn't matter how many rows there are.

Answer (score 0):

use a `BoxView` overlaid on your `Grid` to simulate a separator

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

    <!-- Row 1 -->
    <Label Grid.Row="1" FontSize="Medium" Grid.Column="0" Text="right tst:" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" BackgroundColor="cornflowerblue" />   
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding drain1vol}" BackgroundColor="cornflowerblue"/> 

    <! thin separator -->
    <BoxView Color="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HeightRequest="2" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    <!-- rain1 Row 1 -->
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="nothing"  BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>               
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding drain2vol}" 
HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="Yellow" /> 

    <! thick separator -->
    <BoxView Color="Black" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HeightRequest="5" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: this will only work if i have a fixed number of rows right? but if the rows are unpredictable like I may have 8 rows, I have to know which row will the boxview be?

Comment: If you're doing it in XAML how are you going to have a flexible number of rows?  But there's no reason you couldn't do it in code and adjust to fit the number or rows you actually have

Comment: with your answer it seems that the best solution to work with boxview is with a fixed rows so I would know where to put the thin separator.  Or i could name the boxview and call that boxview with thick separator when it's the last row.